# Python slice assignment in the reverse order doesn't work! Why?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, variable-assignment, slice

There's not much discussion about how Python actually assigns lists to slices of an existing list.

For example, I did the following:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

l[2:5:1] = [7,7,7]

print l #prints [1, 2, 7, 7, 7, 6]

g = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

g[5:2:-1] = [7,7,7]

print g #prints [1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 7]

h = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

h[2:5:1] = [7,7,7,7]

print h #prints [1, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6]


k = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

k[5:2:-1] = [7,7,7,7]

print k #gives a runtime error
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/0mDBg7

Can someone please explain how this works, and why the last example does NOT run successfully as the one just above it (runs for h, but not for k)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `step` of the length of slice is not 1, the length of the slice and the length of the assigned sequence should match.

```
>>> k = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> len(k[5:2:-1])
3
>>> k[5:2:-1] = [7,7,7]  # This is okay, lengths are same.
>>> k
[1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 7]

>>> k[5:2:-1] = [7,7,7,7]  # not okay
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 4 to extended slice of size 3
```

If the length of the slice 1 (default), it's okay to assign a sequence that has difference length; this will change the length of the list.

```
>>> k[1:5] = [1]
>>> k
[1, 1, 7]
```